# Can ColdFusion access a website and fill out a form? How?

Tags: coldfusion

I have an application written in VB.NET that creates a website object, hides it, and then fills out and submits forms on that website.

Can this be done in ColdFusion? What is a common method used to do so? Any good resources?

Comment: When you say it submits forms on that website, do you mean that it creates forms that users fill out and submit, or that the server itself sends information to another page via a form post?

Comment: @Sergii is concerned because your question is both bage and seemingly about very basic concepts, which are common features of spanbot questions.  Also, we've never met you, so you might still be a spambot, or a talking squid, or something even wierder. We are, after all, on the internet.

Comment: I always wanted to be a robot, but I wouldn't have picked spambot. Oh well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CFHTTP](http://cfquickdocs.com/cf8/#cfhttp) with the "post" action is functionally the same as submitting a form to the action page/target.

Let's say there's a form like so:

```
<form action="formProcess.cgi" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="firstName" />
  <input type="text" name="lastName" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Your code would look something like this:

```
<cfhttp url="http://example.com/formProcess.cgi" method="post">
  <cfhttpparam name="firstName" value="Claudio" />
  <cfhttpparam name="lastName" value="Ver Night" />
</cfhttp>
```

There are, of course, lots of other options. There are also lots of ways to protect against this sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I needed to get started with.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Ben Nadel's post on how to work within a session. http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1171-CFHTTPSession-cfc-For-Multi-CFHttp-Requests-With-Maintained-Session.htm

Comment: Thanks, this is a great resource. Fantastic!